# File reading - C Course Assignment Question

Tags: c

I am taking an introductory course in C programming and have this assignment.

> Write a program that reads in a
>   regular text file as input and outputs
>   how many of each letter appeared in
>   that file.

Below is what I have so far. The problem is it outputs nothing and I have no idea what to do. I realize in the while loop there isn't a valid expression. I put a placeholder there, "TEST", because I'm not sure what to test to see when it reaches the end of the file. Any ideas?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()  {
    int i, index, chars[256];
    char letter;
    FILE *ifp;

    //sets the value of all the counters to 0
    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        chars[i] = 0;

    ifp = fopen("input.txt", "r");

    //loops through reading each character and then increments the counter by 1
    while (TEST)    {
        fscanf(ifp, "%c", &letter);
        index = letter;
        chars[index] += 1;
    }

    //prints the totals for each character
    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        letter = i;
        printf("%c: %d\n", letter, chars[i]);
    }

    fclose(ifp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Off track a bit. Here is a hint: use an array to hold the counts.

Comment: @Uku Loskit, I think he's just talking about letters, which makes 26 or 52 ifs; but that's still an `if` galore for sure.

Comment: @Uku Loskit ASCII only has 128 symbols, and he's only considering writing `if`s for 52 of them anyway.

Comment: ok, my bad. erroenous comment removed.

Comment: @Uku Loskit @zneak @jwodder @GregS thank you for the hints. The assignment refers only to letters, not symbols and other characters. However, even 52 if statements is crazy. I'm going with the fact that characters are simply integers. Should be much easier.

Comment: Also consider clicking the checkmark next to the answer you feel was the most helpful.

Comment: The name of an int is chars .. Eww.. How about name it count,wordCount or something not having 'char' in it?

Comment: Amazing to see so many answers and comments (some of them really questionable or bad) and yet no answers to a very concrete question :)

Comment: I appreciate your autocritic @zvrba

Comment: `while( (index = fgetc(ifp)) != EOF ){ chars[index] += 1; }`

Answer (score 5):

Off track a little. That would make an `if` jungle, compared to the very concise code it's possible to achieve.

This post assumes you work with the ASCII encoding, which should be true unless you work with a very odd system.

I've got two or three hints for you. First, arrays are great tools to group values together.

Second, characters actually being integers, you can subtract letters from letters.

```
char letter = 'z';
int index = letter - 'a'; // gives 25
```

You may also be interested in the [`isalpha`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/isalpha/) function.

Comment: Also the `toupper` and/or `tolower` functions.

Comment: Technically letters are not required to be contiguous, but this is solvable with `char *alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; size_t offset(char c) { return (size_t)(strchr(alpha, c) - alpha); }`

Comment: but they are in ASCII and ASCII based, and also EBCDIC. Other encodings? Just considereding single-byte encodings of course... I would count all occurrences of bytes as he did and then use isalpha, which should consider the locale too, if I am not wrong, in order to printf the final result counts. So, you count bytes (0-255) occurrences, and then "select" which are alpha(betic) according to isalpha

Answer (score 2):

A major hint would be that each character is really just a number (see [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)). Example: `A` = 65 and `B` = 66. Having a variable for each letter isn't a good idea.

Comment: Excellent. Makes this much easier.

Answer (score 1):

When you consider the fact that there are 26 characters in the (I'm assuming English) alphabet, that would mean an awful lot of `if` statements, all of which would be very similar to one another.  If you are repeating very similar code a lot of times, it's a sign you're doing something wrong.

I'm assuming you've been taught a few basic data structures by now.  Have you thought about storing the counter for each letter in one of those structures?  Remember, each character is really only a number to the computer.

Also, remember that text is more than just letters of the alphabet.  You can probably get a better mark for handling spaces and other characters in a somewhat sensible fashion (in other words: do anything other than ignore the problem).

Comment: Yea, I'm going to store it in an integer array. Now I realize characters are numbers though, that wasn't gone over in class.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reading block by block or line by line instead of character by character. You can create a static int array that has 256 cells and increment proper index according to character. Here is some semi-pseudo code:

```
int chars[256];
char *buffer;

while(len = read_chars_to_buffer(buffer)) {
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        chars[buffer[i]]++;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `chars` array has already been updated (previously it has 255 cells).

Comment: Unnecessary complication, stdio functions do their own buffering for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints that might help,

- You are not checking if the **file is opened successfully**. Lets say the file does not exit. How would the program execute? This is one reason why it might not be displaying anything.
- <del>You can also make all the elements of the array to a value like this,</del>

> <del>int arr[500]={0};</del> // you don't need it now.

- <del>Use a **char type array.** Insert everything from the file into it.</del>
- As zneak mentioned, use isalpha() to check if it's an aplhabet moreover use `isupper()` and `islower()` to check both upper and lower case alphabets.

Comment: Advice about char array is awful.

Comment: +1 for editing the answer; the second point could be left and avoid the zeroing for loop

Comment: We are not supposed to bother with error checking for these assignments. It is assumed that the file is present.

Comment: If you assume that that the file is present then you can also assume that your code outputs something and not 'nothing' as you mentioned. Programming is not assumption. If the file is not going to open then how are you going to do the rest of the work?

Comment: I understand that, but for the purposes of our assignments, the directions clearly state don't do error checking.

Comment: Oh, then its ok. But still it can be one of the reasons that you may get an error.

Answer (score -1):

Simple fix for your program: declare a variable `int ch;` (NOTE: it MUST be int!) and rewrite your while loop as follows:

```
while ((ch = fgetc(ifp)) != EOF)
{
  assert(ch >= 0 && ch < 256);
  ++chars[ch];
}
```

The `assert` is there just in case you run the program on some weird platform where characters are out of the range 0-255.  (Oh yes, you also need to include `<assert.h>`)

Comment: assertions are evil (according to many on SO, I was downvoted once to have used them, though it was appropriate since was just a lazy placeholder for a missing test); moreover, fgetc returns an unsigned char casted to int or EOF, so assertion will never be taken and is pretty unuseful.

Comment: People tend to proclaim as evil things they do not understand. And fgetc returning "unsigned char casted to int"? You have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: I will say it to the >10k rep person who made the downvote. The sentence is taken literally from the man, so send your complaints to whoever wrote it: http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/gets.3.html . -1 for not having the humility to check the claim and for being offensive.

Comment: Except that ANSI C allows unsigned char to be larger than 8 bits, and assert is very much in place there. You still have no clue what you're talking about, as witnessed by your first comment.

Comment: Beisdes, voting is based on technical merit. Your little hurt ego has just admitted defeat. :P

Comment: this is based upon technical+practical demerit that makes your answer not good.Your code makes OP believe it is worth taking into account"weird"platform where1byte has more than8bits.It is not(not here),there are too much other details(even text file portability!)to take into account to make portable code or just code that"recognizes"that it can't run on that platform.How many SO answers do just `getchar()!=EOF`?Would you go and fix them all?Or downvote them because they forget your weird platform?So,yours is a distracting ostentation of(here)unuseful knowledge.Unsigned char will be [0,255].

Comment: About assertions, someone tried to explain to me (not just saying to me "it is absurd what you say!", as you do)when and why they are evil(I am still sure my usage was justified,anyway).I have refined my own judgement capabilities about the subject. Your assertion is evil,since it's misplaced.Let me do as you do: just saying you're wrong without trying to explain more.So,this is another demerit:even though ok considering weird platform,your assertion's usage is bad.

Comment: At this point usually I ignore the answer and avoid downvoting,though deserved.But your first comment(*NO, feof() does not do what...*),which does not explain(a demerit),plus the rest (like *And fgetc returning "unsigned char casted to int"?...* which is misleading),all without constructive explanations made me believe your technical+practical demerits are not in good faith,and need to be stressed a bit. Last (maybe)demerit: you still make readers believe fgetc can return something bigger than a char. And the side-demerit is that you still not understand what I mean. Isnt obvious for your ego?

Comment: of course I don't write everything explicitly - I expect people to think for themselves and investigate. but.. blabla.. please continue your monologue.

Comment: an answer is supposed to be useful,and comments too,in general;they should "complete" or "correct" an answer,not just say "ahah you are wrong!".Saying !feof does not what I think (you pretend you know what I think,and you don't)!=saying !feof won't work with OP's loop as is.The same for <And fgetc returning "unsigned char casted to int"?...>,a man snippet(it seems you're saying "impossible!"Why?).Your usage of assert is wrong(evil and OT).But you havent investigated why,since you can't be wrong;rather,you prefer to say other people do not understand.Yeah you're cooler and smarter,blabla.

Comment: -1 since if weird platforms are a possible concern here, then it is not the right place/way to check for them: this will cause the program to fail at runtime (or never, if the NDEBUG macro is defined), while other problems dued to the odd bits per byte number may occur elsewhere. The program should check CHAR_BIT, asserting CHAR_BIT==8 in the `main` or, better, with an #if and an #error to make the compilation fail.